Spacing around math operators
This has been bothering me for a while now... Consider the expression |\log x| = |{\log x}| = |\log(x)| = |{\log(x)}| which outputs:

Visually, the first and last look "wrong" with too much space preceding the log in the first case and too little space in the last case. The other two cases look about right (but I would probably slightly increase the spacing before the log in the second case and slightly decrease it in the third). Is there a fix so that the \log (and friends) command behaves so that the spacing between the absolute values and the expression they enclose is symmetric for both |\log(x)| and |\log x|?

You should never use |...|. use \lvert ... \rvert the latter has the build in open- and close-ness that pure |...| is missing. Similar to ().

In addition to what @daleif writes, why the braces around the logarithms?

The best solution is to hide away the details in macros, for example using mathtools: \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert, then use \abs{\log x}. Bonus \abs*{\frac12} autoscales and \abs[\big]{x^2} manually scales

@mickep can be convention. For example some of our people wrote a not to be used in statistics for biologists, we had to use \sum\limits_{....} whenever the math was in text mode as the students could not understand what `$\sum_{n=1}^10$ meant.

@mickep That was just a cheap way to reduce the spacing...

@daleif That does the trick, thanks! \left| ... \right| also works but seems to produce different spacing before the opening bar (even when the ... is very low so that the bars that it produces are normal height).

\left...\right produces even worse spacings for other reasons. Try \log\left(x\right), this introduces a space after \log that \log(x) does not have. The \abs solution fixes this for the \abs* version (that internally uses \left...\right in a special way).

@daleif Fair enough, I usually try to avoid \left...\right anyway, that gives me one more reason to do so...

@MartinHairer \left...\right can be fine, when relevant. More often than not, they are too large, or does not do anything. Also note that for the manual ones you should use \bigl( .... \bigr) not \big(...\big) as in certain circumstance the latter has the same issue with the spacing.

This shows the differences
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$|\log x| = |{\log x}| = |\log(x)| = |{\log(x)}|$

$\lvert\log x\rvert = \lvert{\log x}\rvert = \lvert\log(x)\rvert = \lvert{\log(x)}\rvert$

\fboxsep=0pt
$\boxed{)}$
\end{document}


In the box, note how there is extra space on the right of the ), so the that discrepency come from the design of the ).
I tend to recommend using mathtools (disclamer I help maintain it) and this construction
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert

In order to hide all the \lvert ... \rvert stuff away.
Bonus \abs*{...} is similar to \left\lvert...\right\rvert but slightly better horizontal space, and \abs[\big]{...} is the same as \bigl\lvert...\bigr\rvert.
